# Regex for modifying markup of image in post content

Tags: regex, wordpress, image

I want to modify markup of image in post content. I would like to check if there is any image in content like:

```
<img src="/path/to/image" alt="image" />
```

and would like to replace it with:

```
<div class="my-div">
<img src="/path/to/image" alt="image" />
</div>
```

Please tell me how I can do this. I think we would need regex to perform this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(<img .+?/\?>)
```

And replace with:

```
<div class="my-div">$1</div>
```

In PHP you would do:

```
<?php
$string = 'wefwef dfwefrf we<h1>sodm</h1> <img src="some.jpg" />';
$pattern = '/(<img .+?\/?>)/';
$replacement = '<div class="my-div">$1</div>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/7MLilI

Comment: Can you please post complete code ? I am not getting anything out of it. Sorry but I am not good at regex ;)

Comment: No, I want to do it in php + wordpress.